# everything deleted out of btrfs volume, but disk usage is still 95%

Tags: btrfs

I have a btrfs volume that formally had a bunch of read-only subvolumes stored on it.

I deleted them all.  There's no files and no subvolumes, but still no free space.

I tried syncing, still no free space.

I tried `btrfs balance`.   That does not appear to be doing anything and the userspace process is stuck in uninterruptible disk sleep.   I tried `btrfs balance cancel`.   Now that process is stuck in disk sleep too.   Still no free space.

Any suggestions?   Should I just reboot and reformat the volume?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have other volumes above what you have mounted at / or whatever? What about snapshots?

You could use a tool like [btdu](https://github.com/CyberShadow/btdu) to check what's actually happening on a btrfs volume.

Comment: thanks, I tried letting `btrfs balance` run all night, and it did manage to reclaim the space.       So I guess that's the "solution", although I don't love it.